# Use variable declared in Java within SQL query

Tags: java, derby

k so I have created a database called dictionaryDatabase using Apache Derby in Java. The database has a table called dictionaryTable and contains two columns, wrongWord and rightWord. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
String keyWord = "test";

getWords = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT wrongWord FROM dictionaryTable WHERE wrongWord = (?)");
```

Now, for every wrongWord that does match keyWord, I wish to retrieve the value from the rightWord column in the same row in which the wrongWord value matched keyWord.

I have tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
ResultSet existingKeywords = getWords.executeQuery();

while (existingKeywords.next()) {
 //Get rightWord column values here
}
```

What should I be doing here, and am I on the right track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically returning `wrongWord` from this SQL:

```
SELECT wrongWord FROM dictionaryTable WHERE wrongWord = (?)
```

Why not create a SQL like

```
SELECT rightWord FROM dictionaryTable WHERE wrongWord = (?)
```

And on the `while` loop, do

```
while (existingKeywords.next()) {
 //Get rightWord column values here
    String rightWord = existsingKeywords.getString("rightWord");
}
```

Clearly, I'm sucking thumb since I don't know what columns `dictionaryTable` contains so it's an assumption.

Also, I've not shown how manage JDBC connections.